# How to restrict internet access to a subnet, and allow from only another subnet of the same vnet?

Tags: azure, vnet, azure-nsg

How to restrict inbound internet traffic to a Subnet1 and allow traffic to it from Subnet2 of the same vnet? And enable inbound internet traffic to Subnet2.

How to do it in Azure?

```
                        +-----------------------------------+
                        | +-------------+       VNET        |
                        | |             +------+            |
                        | |   SUBNET2   |      |            |
      +---access ---->----+             |      |            |
                        | |             |      access       |
                        | +-------------+      |            |
  Internet              |         +------------++           |
                        |         |             |           |
                        |         |   SUBNET1   |           |
      +--X no access X------------X             |           |
                        |         |             |           |
                        |         +-------------+           |
                        +-----------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no NSG attached to the VM NICs. You could add two inbound security rules in SUBNET1 nsg:

```
Priority    Name          Port    Protocol   Source          Destination   Action
101        allowSubnet2   any     any        Subnet1IPlists  any           allow

102        denyAny        any     any        any             any           deny
```

Add one inbound security rules in SUBNET2 nsg:

```
Priority    Name          Port    Protocol   Source          Destination   Action
101         allowInternet any     any        Internet        any           allow
```